# How to fork my own copy of repository from someone else?

Tags: git, github

I had a repo on which I had made several changes and accidentally lost my previous directories but luckily someone forked my repo before these changes happened and has all the files that I need so how do I fork my own repo from that someone? The fork repo option in github does nothing but take me to my own repo but without the changes. Please help me!!

Comment: You're doing forking wrong if it does nothing. Of course, you can always clone the repo to a local disk and re-upload it to your account.

Comment: Why aren't your "previous directories" all in the Git history? If they're in the forked repo they should be in your repo.

Comment: Bcoz I committed changes and accidentally lost the other directories that I had previously to the commit.I know I am doing it wrong that's why I am asking you guys for help.

Comment: Like I said, if they're in the fork they're in your history. You'll need to share more details.

Comment: You don't need to fork your friend's repo. All you need to do is clone it, and push the right commit back from that clone to your own fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your friend's fork has the commit you want, you can create a sandbox with two remotes, fetch the commits from one, and push them to the other.

Assuming you already cloned yours, say

```
git clone my_url
```

then in that sandbox, add a second remote

```
git remote add friend friend_url
```

Fetch the commits from there

```
git fetch friend
```

Reset you local branch to where it's at on their fork

```
git checkout branch_name
git reset --hard friend/branch_name
```

And push that to your repo

```
git push origin branch_name
```

If Git complains that it's not a fast-forward push, then add `--force` to the push command, after making sure you really don't want to keep the history you currently have for that branch on your own repo.

You can repeat this operation for any branch on their fork that you want to bring back in your own repo.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you don't have the branch at all, you can skip the "reset --hard" step, as the checkout step will have found the "friend" copy already.